# Show that f is a constant function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f:R\to R$ is continuous
and $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le|log|x-y||^3.|x-y|^\frac{11}{10}$$
for $x \not= y$ in $R^+$
Show that $f$ is a constant function.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
$$\lim_{t\to0^+} x^\alpha\log^\beta t=0\qquad\text{for all $\alpha,\beta>0$}\tag{1}$$

Now from the hypothesis we have
$$0\le\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\le |x-y|^{1/10}\log^3(|x-y|)$$
now we pass to the limit $y\to x$ and by the change of variable $t=|x-y|$ we see using $(1)$ that 
$$f'(x)=0\iff f \;\text{is a constant function.}$$